# How do I update a table's schema with a new custom schema I have created?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, schema

I am using SQL Server 2008 Express and Sql Server Management Studio 2008.

I am trying to associate a database table with a new schema.

I have created a new Schema by navigating to Security->Schemas in object explorer. I right clicked on the folder and created a new schema called 'People' and set the owner as db_owner.
This new Schema now appears in object explorer.

I would now like to associate a table with this schema. I open the table in design view and click on the drop down list in the table Properties pane which contains the available schemas but my newly created schema is not visible.

I have tried refreshing everything throughout object explorer. Closing design view and reopening etc. but still it isn't there.

Am I doing something wrong?

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted.... absolutely ridiculous!

I had to close management studio and re-open it. Only then had the Schema list refreshed to include my new custom Schema.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of objects (tables, views, etc.), you may want to use one of the system tables to generate scripts for altering the schema of each object.